# DateDiff returns Null or vbNull but cannot check for it in an if statement

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Let me get some questions out of the way up front:

- Yes, I'm having to maintain some legacy code.
- Yes, I realize it's archaic and outdated and terrible.
- Yes, sometimes a date I'm receiving is a NULL.
- No, I cannot switch to something newer.

I have the following piece of code:

```
If DateDiff("y", Date(), someDate) > 0 Then
    'Do something here
End If
```

However, I've found that someDate **can** be `NULL`.

I decided to look up what DateDiff would return in the instance that it received a NULL date. [Microsoft's reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is mum about it.

So, I decided to do my own testing and see if I could find out:

```
Response.Write TypeName(DateDiff("y", Date(), NULL))
```

This outputs `Null`.

```
Response.Write VarType(DateDiff("y", Date(), NULL))
```

Outputs `1` which is equal to `vbNull`.

So, I tried the following (I also tried comparing with `vbNull`):

```
If DateDiff("y", Date(), NULL) = NULL Then
    Response.Write "Yes"
Else
    Response.Write "No"
End If
```

This outputs `No`...

Here's the crazy part...

I tried reversing the comparison:

```
If DateDiff("y", Date(), NULL) <> NULL Then
    Response.Write "Yes"
Else
    Response.Write "No"
End If
```

It still outputs `No`...

What is going on here? How can I check this return in an if block? Am I losing my mind?

Comment: Just try `If IsNull(DateDiff("y", Date(), NULL)) Then ... `

Comment: I would check `IsNull(someDate)` in a separate condition, because you have 3 cases anyway (date is `Null`, date difference is greater 0, date difference is less or equal 0) and this way avoids pointless date calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `IsNull()` function. You cannot compare against vbNull using the `=` comparison operator - it must be checked with the function. The statement `Null = Null` actually equates to false, which goes some way to explaining your strange test results.

Comment: The reason for this behavior is that `Null` is defined as a value that is unequal to any other value, including other `Null` values.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the clarification! You too Polly. Didn't know this about VBScript.

Comment: More precisely, `Null [comparison operator] Null` evaluates to "not true". It isn't *false*, per se, but it isn't true, either.